# how to create shopping cart popup window in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I'm developing e-commerce project using codeigniter..i'm new to codeigniter.now i'm working shopping cart module..i want create a shopping cart popup window in codeigniter..i have used bootstrap modal window but i couldn't able to pass the product values so i didn't view cart details.how to pass values to jquery pop-up window for shopping cart.whenever i click the add to cart button the values to be stored in cart table and also display values in jquery pop-up window.i have spent more time but i can't get proper solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call a ajax function on onclick like this :-

```
<a value-id='1' href='#myModal' class='marker' title='Edit'  onclick="functionname(passifvalueisdynamichere)">click on me</a>
```

Now if required get value from server side then you can call like :-

```
function functionname(id) {
        xmlhttp = getobject();
        var query = "id="+id+"&action=setdraftMessage";
        var base_url = document.getElementById("baseurlval").value;
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                var newArray = new Array();
                      ////get value from server side///////////////
                var result = xmlhttp.responseText;
                ///setvalue like///
document.getElementById("mailid").value =newArray[0];

            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", base_url + "index.php/pass/index?type=setdraftMessage&"+ query, true);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
    }
```

Comment: the above code will be display in div format but i want to load popup window

Comment: you told this line right document.getElementById("mailid").value =newArray[0];

Comment: yes in this line document.getElementById("mailid").value =result;

Comment: here mailid is the part or that will come on modal

Comment: i have javascript .In my Console window ReferenceError: getobject is not defined
so i didn't get popup window

xmlhttp = getobject();